# Generating dynamic forms from schemaless JSON

Tags: reactjs

I have a Mongodb document which im getting data to my React web-app , the problem is i need to generate dynamic text inputs for each property on the mongodb document, but since its a schemaless scenario im not sure how i would achieve this. Any ideas to point me on what to look for?

this is the type of json im getting

```
data = [ { name: 'daniel',numero:'51251241',id: '1'},{name:'bruno',profissao: 'bombeiro'} ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the `data` then use `Object.entries` again to map the objects. I didn't use `key` for the mapped elements. It would be better if you find or create some unique keys.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      { name: "daniel", numero: "51251241", id: "1" },
      { name: "bruno", profissao: "bombeiro" }
    ],
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
      {
        data.map( el =>
          Object.entries( el ).map( ([key,value]) =>
          <div>
            <p>{key}</p>
            <input value={value} />
          </div>
          )
        )
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```